# Recursively remove portion of filename that matches a pattern

Tags: unix

I'm on a UNIX system. Within a directory (and any of its subdirectories), I'm trying to rename all files that match a certain pattern:

**change** hello (1).pdf 
**to** hello.pdf

Based on the top response from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/213134/recursively-rename-files-change-extension-in-linux), I wrote the following command:

```
find . -name '* (1)*' -exec rename -ns 's/ (1)//' {} \;
```

The `find` works on its own and the `rename` also works on its own, but the above command only outputs `Reading filenames from STDIN` and does nothing. How can I make this work?

Comment: I suspect you have the wrong `rename` on your system (see [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/217726)). You want the Perl one.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I downloaded this `rename` from homebrew (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename), which looks like it should be the Perl version, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That looks right to me. Did it work for you? If not, are you sure you're calling the new `rename` you just installed and not the old one you already had?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the tip! Tried replacing in a different format using the -s flag and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out! For whatever reason, it only works when you use the [Perl version](http://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename) of `rename` like this:

```
find . -name '* (1)*' -exec rename -f -s ' (1)' '' {} \;
```